Passing Rmarkdown html widgets to Shiny
I have the following interactive Rmarkdown file and I want to pass it to Shiny as I want to download it as both a word document and I want to display a preview of it. As you can see in the Rmarkdown file, I have a plotly plot where the user can interact with it.
Rmarkdown
---
title: "test_plotly"
output: html_document
date: "2024-05-28"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
library(plotly)

plotly::plot_ly(data=cars, type='scatter',mode='lines')%>%
  add_trace(x=~speed,y=~dist)

This is the shiny app output but the plotly plot doesn't display and I don't want a static plotly plot, I want the interactive one displayed. How do I do that?
library(shiny)
library(knitr)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    uiOutput('markdown')
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$markdown <- renderUI({
    HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('test_plotly.Rmd',  quiet = TRUE), fragment.only=TRUE))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


You can use an iframe to display the resulting HTML file. Please see this related answer.
